# Find a and b such that ? ..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find $a$ and $b$ such that

$\begin{bmatrix}-5\\-11\\14\end{bmatrix} = a$
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix} + b$
$\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$

a = ?

b = ?

I haven't done matrixes in a while. How would I go about doiing this?

Comment: You would obtain a system of three linear equations with two variables. The elementary way of doing this is by Gaussian Elimination. Maybe have a read over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: I apologize, typo on my part in the OP, edited the last matrix to the correct numbers now.

Comment: a = 3 , b = -4 i got it!

Comment: It's a bit unclear are a and b numbers or matrix

Comment: Definitely numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
  & \left\{ \begin{matrix}
   a+2b=-5  \\
   -a+2b=-11  \\
\end{matrix}\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow  \right.\,\,a=3\,\,\,,\,\,\,b=-4 \\ 
 & \left
\{ \,\,\,\begin{matrix}
   a+2b=-5  \\
   2a-2b=14  \\
\end{matrix}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow  \right.\,\,a=3\,\,\,,\,\,\,b=-4 \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I apologize, typo on my part in the OP, edited the last matrix to the correct numbers now.

Comment: It does have a solution, I just made a typo.